# Has anyone used any particular ingredients to create medicinal brews?

Tags: ingredients

I ask this question because while cooking rhubarb, I thought waste not, want not, and decided to chuck the left over liquid into a container and add a bit of yeast to see what I ended up with.

I managed to get a quite nice, and really light wine, but due to a shortage of bottles had to fill up a large jar with a tap on it.  I figured I had better quickly drink the jar to ensure it didn't spend too long exposed to any air the jar took in.  The result was that I discovered that rhubarb wine can definitely act medicinally if the ailment involves not being able to make as much use of the bathroom as you would really like.

Since then I have looked into the medicinal benefits of elderberry wine as I have quite a lot of that around here.  I read that amongst other things it can help loosen up congestion and help a person breathe better.  After a couple of glasses, and armed with this knowledge I can definitely state that this appears to be the case.  The air seems much more fluid at the moment.  Quite nice considering my house can get a bit stuffy at times.

I was wondering if other people had tried using different ingredients to obtain medicinal effects, and which type of ingredients have which kind of effects.  I think I could justify this part of my life a lot better if I can tell people I am just advancing the field of medicine. ;)

Comment: Can you re-word the side effect of rhubarb wine? I'm not following what you are referring too.

Comment: @Chad he's being delicate. To put it indelicately he's made a laxative. To the OP, are you sure the rhubarb was the laxative or did you get some yeast in the wine that you drank?

Comment: Rhubarb is high in oxalic acid. Increases risk of kidney stones in small amounts. Increases risk of kidney damage in large amounts. Not sure about laxative effect.

Answer (score 1):

I've used ginger before, it has been known to have medicinal properties.  If I'm not mistaken I think juniper berries, quinine (tonic water base) and other traditional additives to gruits are probably good things to try (woodrow, flowers, etc.) And if u live in a place where it is legal - cannabis is a good addition.

Hope it gives some ideas to try!

Cheers